# Python: При конкатенации строк происходит их перенос вместо слияния

Tags: python, строки

Пишу обработчик текстовых файлов на Python. Вместо конкатенации двух строк он ставит между ними перенос строки. Как этого избежать?

Имеется текстовая строка вида

> 14:59:40.381 >> 56 01 00 00 00 30(lf)

Мне нужно просто добавить комментарий в конец этой строки, но при конкатенации или при f-строчировании комментарий добавляется на следующую строку.

```
if line[16:18] == '56':
    line = f'{line} {"Вход в режим (48) "}'
output.write(line)
```

Ожидаемый мной результат:

> 14:59:40.381 >> 56 01 00 00 00 30 Вход в режим (48)(cr lf)

А вместо этого всегда получается:

> 14:59:40.381 >> 56 01 00 00 00 30(cr lf)
> Вход в режим (48)

То есть перенос строки вставляется на место соединения строк, а не остается в конце. Помогите разобраться, почему так происходит и как это изменить?

Переносы строки заменяются с (lf) на (cr lf) так как оригинальный файл из линукса, а я выполняю программу под виндой.

Полностью программа лежит в https://github.com/silverjohnes/evo_kkm_reader. Запускается reader.py, обработка строк описана в sys/ops.py. В результате обработки создается output_logs.txt с результатом.

Comment: А зачем литерал строки вставлять так, не проще как есть: `line = f'{line} Вход в режим (48) '`?

Comment: Насчет переносов. Можно, например, через `rstrip` чистить строку от `\r\n`, добавить справа ту строку с входом в режим и добавить `\r\n`: `line = f'{line.rstrip("\r\n")} Вход в режим (48)\r\n'`

Comment: Поменял способ ввода литерала, но ничего не изменилось. Насчет подсказки как чистить результат — спасибо, но не хотелось бы чистить. Почему изначально там перенос строки появляется?

Comment: Не появляется, а был там. У вас в `line` уже были символы перевода каретки и переноса строки и вы к этой строке добавили другую. Просто так символы не добавляются в строках :) Метод `output.write` запишет что вы ему передали и не будет различать где строки, а где непрерывный поток данных

Comment: Делать `line.strip()` - совершенно нормальная практика

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, rstrip() решил вопрос.